# Describing the speed of an object in correlation with time

Tags: kinematics

Lets say an object is not moving with a constant velocity. Now someone comes and finds an equation describing how the speed of that objects changes through time, lets say for the sake of the example is, $v(t) = x^2(t) + 1$.

Now my question is, what is the process, measurments we need to make in order to describe the motion of an object like that. Thanks.

Comment: Your question has unit problems as on the left you have $m/s$, on the right you have $m^2$ added to no units.  Can you clarify?

Comment: What more than *One needs discrete measurements in time.* are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Determining the law that controls the motion of an object is in general impossible without further assumptions.

Suppose you have a number of observations $(x_i, v_i, t_i)$ of where it is, the velocity, and time. A description of the motion of the object is some function $$v(t)=f(x(t),v(t),t)$$ (and the position is the integral of the velocity $x(t)=\int_0^t v(u) du$). The problem here is that between the observations the object may be doing *anything*. Maybe you always see it at $x=0$, but between your observations it shoots off to a remote location and then returns. Maybe it even teleports! The problem is that just using the above equation and trying to fit a function $f$ to the observations is underconstrained: there is an infinite number of functions that could fit your observations.

However, most of the time there are constraints that make things easier. Non-quantum objects don't teleport: $x(t)$ is a continuous function of time. If it obeys Newton's law $F=ma$ and doesn't change mass we know $v(t)$ will be the the integral of the force divided by the mass, $v(t)=(1/m)\int_0^t F(u) du$. Some forces like gravity only depend on location and not velocity. And so on.

Normally one starts from the simplest possible force laws and builds more elaborate models if needed, stopping when it looks like most observations can be accounted for. There will usually be measurement noise in the observations so the fit will not be perfect, so one uses some measure of how well the data and model fits and selects the simplest model with the least deviation.

For example, suppose I start by assuming the object is subject to a constant force $F$. Then the motion will be $x(t)=x(0)+v(0)t +(F/2m)t^2$. I fit the initial position, velocity and force-mass ratio as well as I can to the data. If the fit is good, I settle for that model. If not I may try a force that varies with location, $F(t)=F(x(t))$. Now the motion will be a set of differential equations and fitting a function $F$ to the data will be more complex. But I can also notice that I can rule out this model completely if I see different accelerations at the same location - by assumption they have to be the same, so if they aren't I know I can discard this whole approach. Another model might be a force depending just on velocity, or an even more complex that depend on both position and velocity but not time. As I consider ever more complex models there are more and more degrees of freedom and a good fit becomes less impressive since you can fit any data to a sufficiently complex model.

Usually in physics the solution is to use extra constraints like energy conservation, that the system likely runs on electromagnetism and hence has to have electromagnetic force terms, and so on. But the deep problem is that unless you truly understand what the system is doing you can always fit complicated models to it. And to understand a system largely means that you have a good mental model of what it is about. But we can at least look for simple models that fit with standard physical phenomena.